# How can I specify two actions mapped to the DELETE verb in a rails resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have an api tokens controller based on Matteo Melanis [blog post](http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/). I'd like to add two custom actions `register` and `unregister` to the controller, and so the route that looked like this

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1  do
    resources :tokens,:only => [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

has now become this

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1  do
    resources :tokens do
      put 'register', on: :member, as: :register
      delete 'unregister', on: :member, as: :unregister
    end
  end
end
```

This is the only way I've found that doesn't let `unregister` suppress the CRUD `destroy` action, associated with the `DELETE` verb. I tried to do

```
resources :tokens, :only => [:create, :destroy, :register, :unregister] do
```

in the above code, as well as defining `resources :tokens,:only => [:create, :destroy]` in parallel to the block. Yet, I either get the undesirable all CRUD + custom actions, or one of the custom actions overriding a CRUD action.

In short, I'd like to end up with

```
     register_api_v1_token PUT    /api/v1/tokens/:id/register(.:format)   api/v1/tokens#register
   unregister_api_v1_token DELETE /api/v1/tokens/:id/unregister(.:format) api/v1/tokens#unregister
             api_v1_tokens GET    /api/v1/tokens(.:format)                api/v1/tokens#index
                           POST   /api/v1/tokens(.:format)                api/v1/tokens#create
                           DELETE /api/v1/tokens/:id(.:format)            api/v1/tokens#destroy
```

Is this possible, and if yes: how can I make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
resources :tokens, only: [:create, :destroy] do
  member do
    put 'register'
    delete 'unregister'
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! And more pleasing to the eye ... what a treat! :)